# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting a null reference exception on the below line:

```
foreach (var povList in @Model.HomePovsList)
```

This is the code in my view:

```
@if (@Model.HomePovsList != null)
{
    foreach (var povList in @Model.HomePovsList)
    {
            <li>
                 <img alt="" src="@FMAapp.Helpers.ConfigHelper.CDNHost@Url.Content(@FMAapp.Helpers.ConfigHelper.HomePovImage + @povList.ImageUrl)" />
                <div class="orbit-caption">

                    <h2 class="shrink">@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@povList.Headine))</h2>
                    <h2 class="shrink"><strong>@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@povList.Headline1))</strong></h2>
                    <p>@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@povList.SubHeadline))</p>

                      @if (povList.IsExternal != null)
                      {
                         <a class="button" href="http://@povList.LinkTo" target="_blank"> @povList.ButtonText</a>
                      }
                      else
                      {
                           <a class="button" href="@Url.Action(@Model.GetHomeFeaturePovLink(povList.LinkTo).Action, @Model.GetHomeFeaturePovLink(povList.LinkTo).Controller, new { PCTR = @Model.PCTR })"> 
                            @povList.ButtonText</a>
                      }


                    <p><small>@povList.Disclaimer</small></p>
                </div>
        </li>
    }
}
```

In the controller I am assigning like this:

```
var currentPage = new PageProperties(PCTR) {
    HomePovsList = new HomePovRepository().GetHomePovImages(PCTR)
};
```

`new HomePovRepository().GetHomePovImages(PCTR)` returns an `IList<Marketing_HomePov>`.

In my view model, I have this property:

```
public IList<Marketing_HomePov> HomePovsList
    { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `@Model`, use `Model` instead.The @ is redundant here.(in `if` and `foreach`)
2. Make sure you set your `ViewModel` correctly (`@model IEnumerable<YourClass>` for example)
3. Make sure your method doesn't return null.
4. Make sure you pass your model to the `View` when returning it from your `Controller`. `(return View(model))`

Comment: I made sure i was checking for null objects  inside the collection